# Show break lines (&nbsp;) properly

Tags: angular

I have a list of objects where one of the properties is `description` and the value has break lines as `&nbsp;`.

I'm using the normal way to print it in my HTML, take a look below:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items">
   <p>{{item.description}}</p>
</div>
```

and in the result I can't see the break line, What I see is the description as below:

```
line 1 `&nbsp;` line 2 `&nbsp;` line 3
```

and should be something like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&nbsp` is an ISO character, same as space you shouldn't use it to write break lines.

You can use the `<br>` tag and in the binding, use `[innerHTML] ="ítem.description"`.